# Volatile keyword usage in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am unable to understand that if my variable is both volatile and static then why threads are not reflecting the common shared value in the output
Output of last few lines is :
Thread is running
4998Thread-0
Thread is running
4999Thread-0
Thread is running
4899Thread-1
Thread is running

```
public class Test implements Runnable{
  volatile static int  i=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(;i<5000;i++)
        {   try {
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
      String name = t.getName();
      //  Thread.sleep(10);
                System.out.println(i+name);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println("Thread is running");
    }}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t=new Test();
    Thread t1=new Thread(t);
    Thread t2=new Thread(t);
    t1.start();
      // t.run();
       t2.start();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volatile ensures that changes to the variable are visible to other threads. But it **does not ensure synchronization**.

From one execution of your program I get this output :

```
Thread is running
3474Thread-1
Thread is running
3475Thread-0
Thread is running
3477Thread-0
(.... many lines where i goes from 3478 to 4998, with Thread-0 always being the one running...)
Thread is running
4999Thread-0
Thread is running
3476Thread-1
Thread is running
```

This happens because threads get slices of processor time to be run and their execution can be paused and resumed at any point.
Here Thread-1 is executing line "System.out.println(i+name);" with i having a value of 3476. i+name is evaluated to "3476Thread-1" but just then the Thread-1 execution stops and instead Thread-0 gets its time slice. Thread-0 executes till finalization. And then Thread-1 gets again to execute. We have left it **after** i+name had been evaluated to "3476Thread-1" and before the call to println. The call is now completed and printed, hence you see "3476Thread-1" at then end. i has been increased to 5000 by Thread-0 but that does not change the result of the evaluation of i+name which was done **before** all those increases.

The problem is that i++ and i+name are different instructions and thread execution can be paused and resumed between them. To ensure that you get a secuential output you need to ensure than there is no interruption between i++ and i+name. That is, you need to make that set of instructions atomic.

```
public class Test implements Runnable{
    static Object lock = new Object();

  volatile static int  i=0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(;;)
        {
            try {
                Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
                String name = t.getName();
                synchronized( lock )
                {
                    if ( i>=5000 )
                        break;
                    i++;
                    System.out.println(i+name);
                }
                //  Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Thread is running");
            }
    }   }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t=new Test();
    Thread t1=new Thread(t);
    Thread t2=new Thread(t);
    t1.start();
      // t.run();
       t2.start();
    }
}
```

In that program, if Thread-1 gets paused between i++ and i+name it will be inside the a critical section controlled by synchronized(lock). When Thread-0 gets to execute it will reach the synchronized(lock) instruction and will have to stop executing until Thread-1 resumes and gets out of that block. Because the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) ensures that :

> The synchronized statement (§14.19) computes a reference to an object;
>   it then attempts to perform a lock action on that object's monitor and
>   does not proceed further until the lock action has successfully
>   completed. After the lock action has been performed, the body of the
>   synchronized statement is executed. If execution of the body is ever
>   completed, either normally or abruptly, an unlock action is
>   automatically performed on that same monitor.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a compound (multi step) operation like `i++` on a volatile variable.

You can have both threads retrieve the value, increase it, and write it back resulting in one lost increment (as you see in your example).

Comment: what do you mean by compound ?
can you please modify the part that need to be changed ?

Comment: A compound operation is something that involves multiple steps. Volatile can make sure that assignment and retrieval operation works, but `i++` consists of retrieval, increment and assignment operations, which is 3 in total. You need synchronization to make sure that other threads don't get "in between".

Comment: Or in computer science language  `++` is not an atomic operation.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut Yes, a compound operation instead of an atomic one.

Comment: _You can't use a compound (multi step) operation like i++ on a volatile variable._ That is not true at all.  Of course you can do it.  The OP _did_ do it.  I think what you meant to say is that making a variable `volatile` will not magically make code that uses the variable thread safe.

Comment: @Kayaman  `i++` is compiled into a sequence of Java byte codes that fetch the value of `i` into a temporary location, compute the new value, and then store the new value back into `i`.  If two threads do that at the same time, they could both read the same value, both compute the same new value, and both store the same new value back into `i`.  The result would be that `i` would only increase by 1 even though _two_ threads "incremented" it.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes, as you see that's exactly the situation I described in my post. The second paragraph.

Comment: The problem is bigger than that. That program would work incorrectly even if i++ was atomic.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Well that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet I learned usage of volatile keyword from:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class VolatileDemo {
    private volatile static boolean stop; //remove volatile keyword to see the difference
    private static int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread otherThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!stop)
                    i++;
            }
        });
        otherThread.start();
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stop = true;// main thread stops here and should stop otherThread as well
    }
}
```

If you want to observe what volatile does, try to remove it and then follow the execution, this should be obvious after you run those two versions, but basically keyword here prevents java compiler from assuming that stop condition never changes, it will be read every time the condition gets evaluated. Neat, isn't it?

By looking at your code the problem isn't with usage of volatile keyword, the problem is that the expression `i++` is not atomic. It actually is 3 step operation:

```
1) fetch value of i;
2) increment i;
3) save new value of i
```

When multi-threading comes into play, these might or might not be mixed with other thread's instructions.
So the execution might look like that as well:

```
1) T1: fetch i;
2) T2: fetch i;
3) T1: increment i;
4) T2: increment i;
5) T1: save i;
6) T2: save i;
```

If `i` was `0` you thought you will get `2` as the output, and here's `1` instead.

Go with synchronization, which is pretty simple when not overused and well thought.

Suggested read on [synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Answer (score 0):

If two threads are both reading and writing to a shared variable, then using the volatile keyword for that is not enough. You need to use synchronization in that case to guarantee that the reading and writing of the variable is atomic.

Therefore you need to use synchronization when you modify the i value.

Comment: Volatile ensures you read the right current value , but if two thread read the same value, then its the point of conflict.